# Android SDK error occurs when trying to build an Android Unity game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, sdk

When I try to build Unity project(Android), it says:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to update the SDK. Please run the SDK
>   Manager manually to make sure you have the latest set of tools and the
>   required platforms installed.

Here are the things I tried to fix it:

1. Add `sdk/tool/bin` to the path. Then from cmd, I tried `cd ~\tools\bin` then typed `sdkmanager.bat`
   but it gives me:

   > Error: Could not find or load main class Projects\Android
   >   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Projects\Android
2. From Android Studio went to configuration, downloaded sdk platforms 16-29, all of sdk tools.

Still I cannot solve the problem. Am I missing something? Or did I do something wrong here?

I am using Windows 10.

[Unity error when trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99mfU.jpg)

[Trying to open sdkmanager.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFjGp.jpg)

[Path Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ7EB.jpg)

[Android Studio configuration - SDK Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SKAj.jpg)

[Android Studio configuration - SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL89b.jpg)

Comment: If you click the `Unable to update the SDK.` error in the Unity console, it will show you what the actual error that sdkmanager.bat is having. You should add that error to your question if my answer doesn't solve it.

Comment: sorry for missing it out. I thought it would be unnecessary. However, it works now :) thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using two different instances of the Android SDK. The one Android Studio uses (`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`) and the one you are trying to use in Unity (`C:\Unity Projects\Android SDK\tempToolsDir\`).

There are known issues/warnings about using Android SDK in a path with spaces. You are getting an error related to this when you tried to run `sdkmanager.bat` manually. (The spaces causes the path to be broken into multiple arguments which is why it displays the error about not finding a class called Projects\Android.)

My recommendation is to change the sdk location used in Unity to the path used by Android Studio, or at least a path that doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Don't forgot to mark an answer as approved if it fixed your issue.